# hedge ratio, calculating exposure and perfect hedge

Tags: hedging

[image]

Hi I know how to get the hedge ratio it is 0.9 but what is the companies exposure is it just 1 million? Once I know exposure I can calculate the rest of part (a).

For part (b) I can someone explain this statement to me I know the answer is false just from previous questions on other papers but I don't know why it is false, to be honest, or how to give a counter example.

Comment: Statement "b" is missing a verb.

Comment: For part b - write the formula for the hedge ratio, and think about what it means for a hedge to be "perfect"

Comment: A perfect hedge = a hedge where the variance of the "hedging error" is zero. The "hedging error" plays the same role that the "regression error" plays in regression. You might want to think what is a "perfect regression", it is not the same as a regression with a slope of 1.

Comment: ya i get now thanks guys

Comment: Does anyone know what the company exposure is?